# Cordova scanner throws error for windows phone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows, cordova-plugins

I am trying to build barcode scanner for android and windows phone using cordova barcode scanner plugin.For android it works fine but for windows phone it throws "missing command error" as and when the scan event is called.
Can somebody help me with the issue?